# Python call to 'ibm_db.exec_imediate' gives message 'Function (%s) returns too few values'

Tags: python, sql, db2, informix

I am calling a stored procedure with ibm_db like this:

```
SQL = "EXECUTE PROCEDURE db_x:example_procedure(8, 1234567)"
stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, sql)
```

But line exec_imediate gives the error: ***Transaction couldn't be completed:[IBM][CLI Driver][IDS/UNIX64] Function (%s) returns too few values. SQLCODE=-685***

In the IBM site we have the following:

```
685 Function <function-name> returns too few values.
The number of returned values from a function is less than the number
of values that the caller expects.
```

I dont know where exactly the error occurs and why? How can I debug this and solve it?

Ps.: I do not have access to the procedure code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **ibm_db** uses **DRDA** protocol, and it is not a best choice with Informix database. You may try the same with Informix native python driver, which is **IfxPy**.

Here is the Informix native python driver homepage
https://openinformix.github.io/IfxPy/

Comment: OK Satyan, I'll give a try...Thanks